# get item on setOnItemClickListener listview by id

Tags: android, listview

how i can get item details on click listview by id, not by position. my code is :

```
listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            //Category category = categoryAdapter.getItem(position);

            Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProductDetailsActivity.class);
            productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position );
            startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
        }
    });
```

that code work and i can view detail my product on another class(ShoppingCartHelper.java). But i want to get details product using id on that product. any advice guys?

Comment: what is the last parameter of `onItemClick` method?

Comment: @pskink its identifier id on class item thats return id

Comment: no, it is: `id: The row id of the item that was clicked`

Answer (score 2):

get `Category id` like

```
listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

Category item=(Category)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

int categoryId=item.getCategoryId(); // get Category Id 

  }
});
```

Comment: in order to get an id see `android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int position)` or .... just use the last parameter of `onItemClick`

Comment: downvote  `id` is passed directly as the last parameter of `onItemClick` method

Comment: no, this is the way to follow, why do you think `id` is passed to that method?

Comment: view id? what are you talking about? better read Adapter's documentation in order to know how the stuff work